# How do I install Gallium3d Drivers in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: drivers, 12.10, ati, uninstall

I am having horrible problems with the latest ATI Graphics Driver. I have an ATI Radeon HD 5800 and I just lost my GUI for Linux (typing this in windows at the moment).

I've read about gallium3d being great drivers, but I can't find anything any where how to install these drivers or where to get them.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find articles and benchmarks of linux display drivers on [Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=category&item=Display%20Drivers).

If you really want to use `gallium3d` drivers, open a terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and follow these instructions (taken from [here](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/)):

1. Add [ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983)) to your system:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`
   `sudo apt-get update`
2. Install the driver:

   `sudo apt-get install libg3dvl-mesa`
3. Restart.

You can revert to the default drivers by removing the PPA as follows:

1. Install ppa-purge:

   `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`
2. Purge the PPA:

   `sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`

Comment: did that, when I got to Step 2: Install the driver I get the following error: E: Ubable to locate package libg3dv1-mesa

Comment: Never mind, It was an L not a 1. That... worked I think. As in it installed something but it doesn't appear to have actually changed anything. My System Settings still says Unknown for the driver.

Comment: Can you post the terminal ouput for `glxinfo | grep 'renderer string'`?

Comment: The program 'glxinfo' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
I ran the install, rebooting to see if that fixed it.

Comment: Thank you @mrcktz Everything works and is installed properly :D